# Заполнить форму данными из API

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть метод `GET /api/1.0/platform/settings`, который выдает список с настройками платформы в формате `JSON`:

```
[{"param":"TTL","value":"25"},{"param":"path","value":"\/media\/cctv"},{"param":"segment_time_min","value":"60"}]
```

Как, силами `jQuery`, спарсить этот массив и сделать из него форму типа такого?
Ах да, есть второй метод апи, который настройки сохраняет, тоже было бы хорошо прикрутить сохранение, ну или направить меня по правильному пути:

```
PUT /api/1.0/platform/settings
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://yastatic.net/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <form action="" method="post">
  <fieldset>
            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="param1">param1</label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="param1" name="param1" value="value1" required class="form-control input-lg">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="param2">param2</label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="param2" name="param2" value="value2" required class="form-control input-lg">
              </div>
            </div>            
   <br>
   <input type="hidden" name="action" value="platform_settings">
   <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Сохранить">
  </fieldset>
  </form>
```

P.S. На `SO` искал, похожего не нашел, а `Javascript` для меня как китайский язык :(

**UPD.**

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/1.0/platform/settings',
    type: "get",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // since we are using jQuery, you don't need to parse response
        drawSettingsModal(data);
    }
});

function drawSettingsModal(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        drawRow(data[i]);
    }
}

function drawRow(rowData) {
    console.log(rowData);
}
```

В функции `drawRow` имеем массив:

[image: Arr]

Куда копать дальше?

Comment: Можно просто почитать http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parseJSON/

Comment: @Dmi 
`jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/api/1.0/platform/settings",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
`
На выходе имеем массив из 3 объектов с param value. А дальше куда копать? Есть ли в jQuery что-то типа foreach? И как потом param и value вставлять в html?

Comment: @Dmi Обновил, см.пост

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вижу, вы уже прошли половину пути. Теперь у вас циклично вызывается drawRaw с параметрам data таким образом:

```
drawRaw({"param":"TTL","value":"25"});
drawRaw({"param":"path","value":"\/media\/cctv"});
drawRaw({"param":"segment_time_min","value":"60"});
```

Теперь внутри функции drawRaw нужно описать создание одного input'а со всеми сопутствующими элементами. Примерно так:

```
html += '<div class="control-group">' +
    '<label class="control-label" for="'+data.param+'">'+data.param+'</label>' +
    '<div class="controls">' +
        '<input type="text" id="'+data.param+'" name="'+data.param+'" value="'+data.value+'" ' required class="form-control input-lg">' +
    '</div>' +
'</div>';
```

Предполагается, что переменная html до первого вызова drawRaw уже содержит описание начала html-формы и после срабатывания всех drawRaw в html будет дописан оставшийся код формы.

Итого, представленный вами код можно привести к такому виду:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/1.0/platform/settings',
    type: "get",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // since we are using jQuery, you don't need to parse response
        drawSettingsModal(data);
    }
});

function drawSettingsModal(data) {
    //часть формы до полей, которые генерируем автоматически
    var html = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://yastatic.net/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">' +
        '<form action="" method="post">' +
            '<fieldset>';

    //генерируем html-код полей с именами и значениями из поступивших данных 
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        html += drawRow(data[i]);
    }

    //часть формы после генерируемых полей
    html += '<input type="hidden" name="action" value="platform_settings">' +
        '<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Сохранить">' +
        '</fieldset>' +
    '</form>';
}

//код из этой функции можно поместить прямо внутрь цикла, а функцию удалить
function drawRow(rowData) {
    return '<div class="control-group">' +
        '<label class="control-label" for="'+rowData.param+'">'+rowData.param+'</label>' +
        '<div class="controls">' +
            '<input type="text" id="'+rowData.param+'" name="'+rowData.param+'" value="'+rowData.value+'" ' required class="form-control input-lg">' +
        '</div>' +
    '</div>';
}
```